# Identify where I am in an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, stringbuilder

I have a string array in C# like so:

```
string[] sites = new string[] {
    "http://foobar.com",
    "http://asdaff.com",
    "http://etc.com"
};
```

I'm using this array in a `foreach` and I would like to be able to add a "type" value of 1, 2, or 3, depending on which site I am currently iterating through. I am concatenating data with the `StringBuilder` from these sites. Now, I could store the site as a `varchar`, but it would be really neat, since this array will NEVER change to associate a number with the string and build it that way.

Comment: Where do you get the "type" value, and for what do you want to use it?

Comment: I am using sharpSVN to get svn data, but I wanted to be able to associate an int value for each of our repos. Essentially, I want SVN data to be automatically inserted in our db using a nightly console app, which we can use on our site to track recent codebase changes. I could just add in the site associated with a varchar, but I thought it would be cool to associate just an int in sql server to identify which site so I could do nifty filtering on the front end if people only want to see changes on "svn://foo/trunk". I think a dictionary will be perfect in this situation!

Comment: If you're associating an `int` to a `string` in a `Dictionary`, you're pretty much setting up an array that'll have bad lookup performance, by the sounds of it. Provided your array doesn't change order, just index the array, and iterate with the index using a `for` loop. That's what arrays are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary for this - `Dictionary<int, string>` (or `Dictionary<string, int>`).

```
var sitesWithId = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
  new { "http://foobar.com", 1},
  new { "http://asdaff.com", 2},
  new { "http://etc.com", 3}
}
```

Another option is to just use a `List<string>` and [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx) to find out the index.

```
var sites = new List<string> {
    "http://foobar.com",
    "http://asdaff.com",
    "http://etc.com"
};

var foobarIndex = sites.IndexOf("http://foobar.com");
```

A third option, using the static [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx) methods of `Array` and not changing your array at all:

```
var foobarIndex = Array.IndexOf(sites, "http://foobar.com");
```

Comment: Awesome! A dictionary is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

Use `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sites.Length; i++)
{
    // use sites[i]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

LINQ's [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) can be used to project an index onto a collection.

```
sites.Select((x, n) => new { Site = x, Index = n })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`for`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop;

```
for(int i = 0; i < sites.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sites[i]);
}
```

using for elements of `sites[]` array like this;

```
sites[1]
sites[2]
sites[3]
```

or you can use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` as Oded [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14417664/447156).